# Ubuntu 18.04 wi-fi adapter not found on Lenovo X1 carbon

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

I have had this computer for almost a year and wi-fi has been working perfectly until today. In the setting under Wi-Fi all I get this the message:

```
No Wi-Fi Adapter Found
```

I do not have an ethernet port so don't know how to connect directly to router.

Running the command lspci gives me:

```
Network Controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
Wireless Controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation Device 7360 (rev 01)
```

I can't type all of the output bc I have to do this from a second computer.

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix without having to connect to the web?

UPDATE Also, if I reboot into Windows then wifi works just fine. The problem is only when I boot into Linux

UPDATE Here is the output from other various commands:

uname -a

```
Linux my-thinkpad 4.15.0-47-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 10:44:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 X86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

sudo lshw

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

lsusb -v & lspci -v give output that is way too long to type here. I cant copy paste bc my linux box is offline so I have to transcribe manually on another machine. What values are you looking for specifically from these commands and I can get them?

Comment: Is the WiFi adapter disabled in the firmware configuration or by a hot-key combination (typically Fn-F8 on Lenovo)?

Comment: F8 key has a picture of a tower with a signal and is crossed out. Hitting Fn-F8 does nothing. Hitting this key by itself just enables/disables airplane mode.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the following ?

- `uname -a`
- `sudo lshw`
- `lsusb -v`
- `lspci -v`

https://paste.ubuntu.com/

---

Try booting Windows and disabling Wake-On-LAN. [image]

Comment: edited original question to give you these answers

Comment: Hmm... There is no Power Management tab in the properties box for me. Only General, Advanced, Driver, Details, Events and Resources. I do not see this option in any of them

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot enabled in BIOS ? I am really at a loss, I will be watching this thread closely.

Comment: According to System Information in Windows it is turned off. Should it be on?

Comment: No definitely off